# OAuthPrompt Waterfall needs to begin twice to let RouteAsync be called more than once

Tags: c#, .net, oauth, botframework

I'm trying to authorize a user with the built in OAuthPrompt. I've combined the virtual assistant template with `BotBuilder-Samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\46.teams-auth` as I will be using the Teams channel for my bot ultimately. My problem occurs based on where in the code I attempt to authorize the user. I've tried two places:

Before showing this, I feel `WaterfallDialog` is a relevant piece. I am using the Waterfall dialog in the 46.teams-auth minus two steps.:

```
AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
{
      PromptStepAsync,
      LoginStepAsync,
}));
```

1. `RouteAsync`

   ```
   protected override async Task RouteAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
   {
       var OAuthResult = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(WaterfallDialog));
       if (OAuthResult.Result == null)
       {
           await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Please press the Login button."), cancellationToken);
       }
       else
       {
             // ... regular route stuff, like luis check etc
       }
   }
   ```

This runs the prompt and I am able to log in, but RouteAsync never gets called again.

2. `OnInterruptDialogAsync`

   ```
   var OAuthResult = await dc.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(WaterfallDialog));
   if (OAuthResult.Result == null)
   {
       await dc.Context.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text("Please press the Login button."), cancellationToken);
       return InterruptionAction.StartedDialog;
   }
   else
   {
       return InterruptionAction.NoAction;
   }
   ```

This allows my user to log in and then interact with the LUIS portion of the `RouteAsync` method (which checks if a user is logged in every time before running any LUIS methods). The issue with this one is that because it is in the `OnInterruptDialogAsync` method when I start the bot in the emulator two threads run through this method and the user gets prompted twice. I've tried to make it so that `dc.BeginDialogAsync(..)` only gets called once by checking if the `dc.ActiveDialog` is not `OAuthPrompt` before calling it, but this only prompts the user once and then never allows them to log in.

I've also tried to set the `InitialDialogId = nameof(WaterfallDialog)` within `MainDialog.cs`'s constructor, but this makes it so the user is never prompted.

Any help with this is appreciated. I'm also open to sharing my project but not in a public place. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps related: when I publish the same bot to Microsoft Teams the `OAuthPrompt` lets me authorize once, and then reprompts me with the `OAuthPrompt`. If I cancel then send a message, the bot prompts the `OAuthPrompt` but this one returns `Unable to sign in. Please try signing in again.` every time until I think my token expires, then the process repeats. Going to keep looking into this.

Comment: Just for clarification, before I attempt to repro: you're currently just trying to spin up a virtual assistant that works on teams and auths the user?

Comment: Hey, sorry. Figured this out, just need to post it as an answer but don't have time right now. Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Sorry - my coworker figured out a solution that works locally and on Teams, but the local version works on his machine only. It would be nice to be able to debug this locally on other machines with the emulator. I could share my code, but also yes it was the virtual assistant with the teams solution for authorizing the user.

Comment: Something that I've noticed: For the machines that this is not working on locally, they are not getting magic codes after the OAuthPrompt and sign-in. On the machine this is working, there is a magic code. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: I think because there is no magic code, my bot isn't getting a POST /api/messages trigger when a user authenticates locally and so it gets confused about where it is in the waterfall...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed by going into bot framework emulator settings (the gear at the bottom left), and under `User Settings` making sure that `Use a sign-in verification code for OAuthCards` is ticked.